# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.<init>(Unknown Source)

Tags: eclipse, api, owl

I am using Hermit reasoner with owl api 4.0, java sdk 1.7, eclipse 3.0.4, jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3 and tomcat 7. I have imported classes

- org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.ReasonerFactory
- org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner

Every thing compiles well. but during application run, i get following error.

```
Sep 24, 2014 1:27:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path   
[/OntSearch] threw exception [Error calling action method of component with id  
frmFlexSearch:_idJsp13] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyID.getDefaultDocumentIRI()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/IRI;
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.structural.OWLClausification.preprocessAndClausify(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.loadOntology(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner$ReasonerFactory.createHermiTOWLReasoner(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner$ReasonerFactory.createNonBufferingReasoner(Unknown Source)
at org.semanticweb.HermiT.Reasoner$ReasonerFactory.createNonBufferingReasoner(Unknown Source)
at org.coas.ui.bean.SearchPetitionUserBean.nounget(SearchPetitionUserBean.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:132)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:70)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be the possible cause of this run time error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current versions of HermiT are not compatible with OWLAPI 4 yet. Use 3.5.1 for the time being, until a new HermiT is released, or build your own from my fork on GitHub. The username is ignazio1977.

I cannot provide a timescale for the next HermiT release, unfortunately.

Edit: The link to download the updated source code is here (still experimental)
https://github.com/ignazio1977/hermit-reasoner

Further edit: Two releases exist for OWLAPI 4.x and 5.x: HermiT 1.3.8.413 and HermiT 1.3.8.500. Both are available on Maven Central.

Answer (score 1):

Update from https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki :
HermiT (org.semanticweb.HermiT.ReasonerFactory, version 4.1.3 support [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sourceforge.owlapi%7Corg.semanticweb.hermit%7C1.3.8.413%7Cbundle)) This is a fork whose purpose is to allow compatibility with 4.1.3.